# How deploy micro frontend on S3

Tags: reactjs, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I'm trying to deploy Micro-frontend on S3, following these instructions:

[deploy micro-fronted on AWS](https://medium.com/swlh/deploying-micro-frontends-to-aws-step-by-step-using-react-webpack-5-and-module-federation-3f97f6f1658c).

There are two apps - Remote and Host.

I was able to see the app after the remote upload was successful.

Following the instructions, I changed the remote property inside the module federation plugin to the url that gets from S3 and points directly to remoteEntry.js.

```
          remoteHome: 'home@http://microfront.poc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/remoteEntry.js'.
```

When I deploy the host and visit the url, the app does not render its content or the remote app. I see the following logs:

1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2. ScriptExternalLoadError: Loading script failed.
   (missing: http://microfront.amazonaws.com/remoteEntry.js)
   while loading "./Home".

any idea how to do that

Comment: Are you sure you configured s3 as a static website? Check this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html to be sure

Comment: @NicollasBraga I checked, s3 configured  as a static website.